# SQL query asking for a value of 0

Tags: sql, zero

I recently started to get into SQL and encountered the following problem:

I've got a table with several employees who went on vacation(the table shows individual vacations)and booked several hotels. One at a time only. 10 hotels stored using IDs 1-10.
[SCREENSHOT OF THE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha67H.png)

when querying how many times a hotel was booked it works fine unless I want to know which hotels wern't booked at all. As soon as I ask for the value of 0 I just returns me nothing
I've encountered similar problems with other queries as soon as I am involving 0 and it really confuses me at this point.

SELECT hotel as HotelNr
FROM vacations
GROUP BY Hotel
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;

^ this works just fine and returns me 3 hotels with their IDs as there are 3 hotels that were only booked once

SELECT hotel as HotelNr
FROM vacations
GROUP BY Hotel
HAVING COUNT(*) = 0;

^this on the other hand returns absolutely nothing

Comment: Alternativly to @Grodon's answer you can make an left outer join from the hotel table to the vakation table. This could be handy if want to see all hotels with their booking-count

Comment: Add tags and state which RDBMS you are using, to start, as it can have different behaviours depending on it and different solutions/approaches

Comment: this may sound a bit silly but how do I know which RDBMS I am using? Since I am not 100% sure what it means.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the hotels that aren't in `vacations`.  You presumably have a separate `hotels` table.  If so:

```
select h.*
from hotels h
where not exists (select 1
                  from vacations v
                  where v.hotel = h.hotel
                 );
```

I don't know what the  matching columns are, but this is the idea.

Comment: this idea worked perfectly...can't believe I didn't spot this earlier. thanks!